# i am trying to print hello world in assembly sublime windows and i get error why?

Tags: assembly

```
{
    "cmd": ["nasm", "-fwin32", "${file}"],
    "file_regex": "^[^/]*\\.asm$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "output": "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.obj",
    "selector": "source.assembly"
}
```

```
section .data
    hello_msg db 'Hello, World!', 0

section .text
    global _start

extern GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess

_start:
    lea ecx, [hello_msg]
    push 0
    push ecx
    push 13
    push 0
    push -11
    call GetStdHandle
    mov  ebx, eax
    call WriteFile
    xor eax, eax
    call ExitProcess
```

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output'
[cmd: ['nasm', '-fwin32', 'C:\\Users\\unknown\\Documents\\ASSEMBLY-CODES\\codes.asm']]
[dir: C:\Users\unknown\Documents\ASSEMBLY-CODES]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.10.1;C:\Users\unknown\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.2\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NAG\EFBuilder 7.1\bin;C:\Users\unknown\AppData\Local\bin\NASM;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin]
[Finished]
```

i am trying to print hello world to the screen using sublime text 3 in windows and that is what i am trying to print and the error and the config i used in sublime but i am getting an error

Comment: I don't know anything about sublime text but it complains about the `output` keyword being unexpected ... so maybe delete that and see what happens.

Comment: now all what i am getting is ``[Finished in 0.1s]``

Comment: Did it produce the object file?

Comment: yes it did i got the obj file

Comment: Then you need to figure out how to link it.

Comment: maybe i need gcc ???

Comment: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html#options : there is no mention of an `output` option there.